# Does ASP.NET Core MVC need JavaScript?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

Can .NET MVC **views** be independent from JS and can effort all JS functionalities for frontend development or we need JS to make a multifunctional dynamic website for some functions that C# cannot cover?

Comment: Have a look at blazor

Comment: no brother, not blazor. I know what blazor is trying to do but I want to know about MVC's view part. Is that depended to JavaScript? Blazor is not in the same demand as MVC but if you are aware, you can share whether it replaced JS and is as competent.

Comment: Theoretically you do not need javascript or jquery in mvc. The question is would that be practical. You will find that out over time.

Comment: if you are working what did you find out? is it needed?

Comment: @MaythamFahmi what do you mean by requirement?

Comment: @MaythamFahmi no no bro, I am not going to those stuff. Practically we need an object in JS for doing something. It became so rich in those because it concentrated on frontend design for long. Now did C# replaced all of them?

Comment: C# in ASP.NET Core MVC does not run in the client's browser. It only runs on the server side. Therefore any interactive elements on the client side would need to be implemented using JavaScript. That's why Daniel mentioned Blazor early on: the point of Blazor is to allow you to run C# in the browser via WASM, which lets you do anything you need on the client side using C# instead of JavaScript.

Comment: Why are you asking this question in the first place? Is it just to avoid learning how to use JavaScript? Knowing the answer to that might help us guide you in the right direction.

Comment: @mason no no. I am thinking whether to take React as frontend and .NET Core for backend or taking .NET Core MVC solely and not taking a special frontend framework as MVC can do the same thing with same capability to do stuff.

Comment: @mason if MVC uses JS, why even bother not taking React as frontend, right?

Comment: @username_allowed Because MVC is all about rendering HTML on the server side, whereas React is all about manipulating the DOM on the client side. In general, if you want to do React or another SPA type framework or Blazor, then you'd use ASP.NET Core as a Web API. Your React/Blazor/Vue/Angular/Whatever app would send HTTP requests to the server when it needs information, and the server would generally respond with JSON. You'd ignore the View part of MVC, but that's perfectly okay.

Comment: @mason it's a good thing the full page doesn't need to be reloaded, right?

Comment: Do you think it would be good if the entire page had to reload every time you opened a menu, or changed a sort option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a question that is quite helpful for choosing your path of concentration from coding manuscript if understood well. Let me tell what it is *theoretically*.

1. The browser that you use understand JS. So, to render anything in the browser, the code that browser will take from server is HTML, CSS, JS.
2. Views in MVC need data to send to the browser, it uses C# for that to communicate with the backend. These pages got embedded Razor markup, they interact with HTML markup, so views can send files in a manner to the browser that got some necessary functionality even avoiding JS in views.
3. Anything advanced that is not defined in those Razor markup that you need to do at frontend with all the information(data) and HTML elements you create, needs to be done with JS.
4. Blazor is an approach to eliminate JS, but that's not the question asked so not related.

Comment: Blazer doesn't eliminate JS. It's a way to write C#, then use tools to translate that C# into JS for the browser to execute. (well mostly, the JS the browser runs is an interpreter, but that's an implementation detail)

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your headline question, does it *need* Javascript? No .Net MVC doesn't depend on Javascript to work, and the file format of the views .cshtml does support some c# for building the view.

Have a look at this for some examples of that:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-8.0

If you wanted to build richer more dynamic interfaces then Javascript is supported, ASP.NET Core MVC projects are very flexible. If you are wanting to go down the component based, c# only route then as mentioned above Blazor is the way forward.

Comment: so ultimately, for more activity JS is needed? C# doesn't cover all of the objects that JS produce for frontend development?

Comment: @username_allowed Since in ASP.NET Core MVC the C# is running on the server side in response to HTTP requests, it is unable to manipulate UI elements in an interactive fashion the way that JavaScript can. This is fine for some simple websites, but not for more complex sites that require a lot of functionality.

Comment: okay, it's getting clearer to me.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like, View in MVC isn't fully compatible to work without JS if complicated functionality is needed.

Comment: You seem to have started this question thread already knowing what conclusion you wanted to reach.  MVC is now deprecated for the most part.  You should be using Blazor.  You can ADD MVC functionality to Blazor if you wish.

The same goes for Javascript.  You can totally create an entire website with no Javascript, but it depends what you want.  If you want to record audio or video, or record video playback, then you'll need Javascript for that.  But it doesn't matter-- because you can use all existing JS very easily using Interop anyway.

Comment: Also, Blazor needs Javascript to run.  It just doesn't need YOU to create any Javascript.  This is an important difference, because if you have an environment with JavaScript disabled for some reason, I'm not sure that Blazor will work.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Thank you. thank you very much for this. No, I wasn't aware to the exact facts and these weren't that clear in web before this question.

Comment: If you leave this thread believing anything other than "Blazor is it.  I should use Blazor," then the question was a waste.  Blazor is all-inclusive: you can add MVC if you want.  You can use JS if you want.  You can render server-side only if you want.  You can render client-side if you want.

Basically, Blazor adds new functionality while preserving total freedom to use whatever tools you want.  No other framework I know of does this.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 okay. that was very helpful. but I actually am not intended to your blazor, instead of I prefer something like React. I am not sure about if blazor will get a good run and gather community supporting the future. wouldn't it be the right approach?

Comment: "Such a good question."  I think it's quite possible that 0 people, ever, are going to benefit from this question.